# Mouseover and mouseout events won't trigger when mouse moves too fast?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-events

I wrote a live demo to show this problem:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/wcczap11

If you move mouse fast between the blue, red and green areas, you will see red 'y' logs are not appear between x and z logs, which means you can't get the red area mouse events.

This is what I want:

[image]

But when mouse moves too fast:

[image]

I just want to know is there a way that no matter how fast I move the mouse the result will always be the same with the first image?

Comment: I'm not completely sure why this question is at -5; please can one or more of the down-voters please add a comment explaining their decision, and offering suggestions on how the question can be improved?

Comment: @AdrianWragg I also have no idea why my question is at -5. Anyhow I changed the title to a more proper one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not completely certain if it affects javascript, but different mice have different polling rates (measured in Hz) and if your mouse is 1000hz and you move 1000px at a constant velocity you should pick up every pixel.

However in reality we move the mouse very fast to begin and slow down as we approach a target to improve accuracy. meaning the first 700ish pixels will have been moved faster than the 700hz could poll and so you're missing values where the mouse moved more than 1px in 1hz.

That's kinda of a dumbed down version (mainly because I don't know everything about it) but basically small-hit-targets are prone to being missed by mousing events.

You could attempt to make target-areas larger, but it still won't fix everything :)

Comment: In your example you can make assumptions that if a user moved from to blue to green then they "should" have entered and left "red" at the intersecting vectors/points between the "enter" and "exit" points of blue and green.

This would require more math than I can conjure on a friday morning, but the logic is sound.

You could extrapolate this theory to other scenarios, too.

Comment: I've made this point against my own answer too, but this hinges on whether OP wants an "over Y" event, or a "moved from X to Z" event - it's possible to take a route that doesn't involve going over Y. They may also go quickly diagonally out of X, such that they do go out of X, over Y (but too quickly to trigger an event) yet miss Z completely.

Comment: agreed, however; it's always possible to leave the browser window completely, and enter on something else, so not sure that changes anything in this regard... I was providing an alternative way of thinking so the OP can approach it differently as there's no way to increase the mouse-polling rate :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is a simple one.

The events aren't being "lost" as such. They are never actually triggering in the first place: due to the speed of transit, at no point is the browser picking up the pointer as being "over". If that's the case, then it can't trigger "out" either, as it was never viewed as being "in" in the first place.

Comment: So, no way to avoid this unexpected behavior?

Comment: There is no way to avoid this without altering other parts of the code - for example, if the user is in X then extending Y to also cover Z, and only shrinking it back down again when the Y:hover is hit.

Comment: As @simey.me said, I think I could use the begin and final state to predict where the mouse must have gone through.

Comment: @YadSmood Using my l33t hacz0r skilz, I just moved the mouse sideways out of X, down, and back in again when I was alongside Z; I didn't go over Y. Are you after a "mouseover Y" event, or a "moved from X to Z" event?

Comment: @YadSmood, @Adrian - You can combine them. If you don't detect an event for `red` then fall back to the "best guess" method I described :)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't get lost. It comes and goes but you cant see because you move the mouse too fast. And in your example it is not lost.

Comment: Please look at my newly added images, the problem did happen. I just want to know is there a way that no matter how fast I move the mouse the result will always be the same with the first image.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a callback that takes too long to execute can cause the browser to skip a poll until the next polling tick (Have you ever seen the `[Violation] 'message' handler took 326ms` console messages?). You're using jQuery to attach the event handlers (and I don't know much about jQuery), so there's a chance that the event handlers aren't passive.